# Issue getting my class to work correctly

Tags: python, class

Quite new to python so I do make obvious or silly mistakes.So I'm creating a socket connection program with one of the functions being able to read specific file types on a computer.
currently I'm using this:

```
def py():
files_py = glob('*.txt*')
for i in files_py:
    print(i)

def txt():
    files_txt = glob('*.txt*')
    for i in files_txt:
        print(i)

def file_choice():
     choices = input("Press:\n\n[1] - .py files\n\n{2] - .txt files\n\n")
     if choices==1:
         py()
     elif choices==2:
         txt()
```

The rest of my code I don't believe relates to this at all. my current issue is that I can access the file_choices first like I want it too. I can then input my option 1 or 2 which should call upon either py or txt class respectively, however, cant get my py() or text() to run. I know my glob runs fine when outside the class so that isn't an issue.I've tried putting a print statement at the start of my classes py() and txt(). not showing up. file_choice will take my option but just seems to ignore the if. any help would be greatly appreciated. I can supply more code but I doubt any will be of any use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part `choices = input("Press:\n\n[1] - .py files\n\n{2] - .txt files\n\n")` will result in `choices` being a string.

Then you are comparing a string to an int, which is not what you want:

`if choices==1:`

So, either do `int(input())`, or `if choices == str(1):`.

Comment: ahh knew it would be something simple. that seems to have worked for me fine. Thank you very much

Comment: @i.darker glad I could help. Please mark it as correct if it worked for you. :)